# structs and arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

I am currently looking at this:

[some Genetic Algorithm](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/csharp8queen.aspx?msg=4117793#xx4117793xx)

This is some adapted code:

```
struct Chromosome
{
    public bool[] genes;
    public int fitness;
}
```

I have never used structs in my evolutionary algorithms/genetic algorithms. Is it not a bit pointless to use arrays in structs - especially when I have to make deep copies? Is there any advantage of using structs in this scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use array of structs but keep in mind the mutable immutable issues one can run into.. also know when and when not to use Structs vs Classes.. have a look at Differences between Structs and Classes in C# just a suggestion

Comment: Actually, I'd worry just about `bool[]` - sounds like you should really be wrapping that into some kind of bit-mask. How many genes are we talking about here?

Comment: Please explean what you mean with EAs and GAs. I think GA is Genetic Algorithm.

Comment: GA = Genetic algorithm, EA = evolutionary algorithm - sorry thought the link would reveal this.

Comment: @Marc Gravell - can you please explain what you mean by bit mask?

Comment: @csetzkorn, we hate clicking links. ;) Generally speaking, we like our questions and answers to be largely self contained.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram - well I have adapted my question.

Comment: @csetzkorn you can use bit operations to access the bits individually, allowing 32 flags per int; a bool array is less efficient

Comment: @Marc Gravell sorry do not understand what you mean

Comment: Each bool in a bool-array takes at least 1 byte, possibly more (4). That is not very memory efficient. A bool-array is just a set of true/false values - well, so is binary, and it is pretty easy to work with integers as binary via bit operators.  Depending on the number of genes we are talking about, this could be "remove the array completely" to "just use a lot less memory". Hence the question: how many genes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, we use a `struct` to represent something that can be considered pretty primitive.  [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx), it should be a type that represents a single "value", 16 bytes or less in size, and so on.

The main thing to keep in mind with a `struct` is the value-type semantics, so passing this in and out of functions will create a copy.  Cost wise this won't be too bad since what you are copying is 1 reference (to the array of bool) and 1 int, but it does create some interesting side effects if you try to modify the array reference in another method or from a copy.

Many people assume `struct` will always be more efficient than `class`, but this is not always the case and usually this micro-optimization is more dangerous than helpful because it introduces the side-effects of working with a value type.

As for the array of `bool` you can either create and set bits in an `int` or use the `BitArray` specialized class in the BCL.

So, the long and the short of it is, if this is legacy code and you want to keep the `struct`, it will work, but it can byte you if you expect it to act like a `class` does when passed/copied.  However, looking at what it's holding, it doesn't meet the MSDN guidance for what `struct` is best suited for.

Comment: I think this Q should be answered in its context, i.e. according to the GA code on CodeProject the author has provided the link. As you can see in the code, all structs are used within a List<> and all of its parameter passing has been performed by ref.

Comment: He asked if it was pointless to use arrays of structs and if structs were valid in this context.  I answered with what structs are typically used for and said it didn't quite fit the context, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problem with this...
In GAs its all about validating the fitness of your candidates. the struct just capsulates all the information for your candidate. therefore the fitness is directly associated with your gene. It makes perfect sense to store it in the same class/struct.

If you do not store the fitness with your gene you have to map it somehow. This would be an unnecessary hassle. Or, if you do not want to store the fitness at all you have to recalculate it evertime you compare two candidates against each other. Would not be wise. especially if the fitness evaluation is rather complex (for example in a GA to evaluate the best parameters for a simulation).

I would use a class that implements the interface IComparable. Two candidates would than be compared by there fitness. Then you only need to sort your list of candidates and pick, for example, the best 10 candidates for the next generation (Always depends on the type of GA you are using).

about the bool array... I don't see any problem with this either. If this is how your gene is represented best... perfect :). The representation as a integer is also fine but in some cases it might make the x-over operation a bit complicated... always depends on the case...

Comment: Sorry but your answer does not say much. I am interested in structs because they be easier (deep) copied/cloned (see GA selection process) and more light weight. However having an object (something on the heap) within the struct seems to defeat the objective ...

Comment: yeah... sorry. i kinda misunderstood the question. I thought the question was about using a struct/class in general and not using a struct instead of a class. my fault

Answer (score 1):

**The bool array will not get deep copied automatically in this case. So you're not really benefitting from structs because when you assign Chromosome to a new one, the reference in both would be to the same bool[ ]**

Instead of using a bool[] you can just use a number: let's say `int`. A chromosome with genes = 3 represents gene: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011. A chromosome with genes = 42134 represents gene: 0000 0000 1010 0100 1001 0110. int is 32 bits which means that you can represent chromosomes with 2<sup>32</sup> genes this way.
You avoid having to worry about deep copying an array and this is faster and more efficient in terms of memory consumption too. Use Int64 if you need more genes.

**Update:**
You're question is so cool btw. In case you have restrictions to the possible gene combinations in some segments, you need to construct the Int32 byte by byte according to the restrictions. To illustrate, I assumed an example for some restrictions on a Chromosome and randomly mutated a Chromosome but with respect to restraints.

```
        //The following creates a random chromosome with restrictions
        //to the genes as described in the following:

        //Let's say that the following pattern must be adhered to: 
        //byte 1 = xxxx xxxx (anything)
        //byte 2 = 1011 xxxx (restricted)
        //byte 3 = [0000 or 1111] xxxx (restricted)
        //byte 4 = 0000 1111 (fixed value)

        Random rnd = new Random();
        byte[] randomByte = new byte[1]; //xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx

        byte restrictedByte2 = 
            (byte)(Math.Pow(2,7) * 1 + Math.Pow(2,6) * 0 + 
            Math.Pow(2,5) * 1 + Math.Pow(2,4) * 1 + 
            rnd.Next(0, 16)); //1011 xxxx

        //in byte 3, the first (most significant) for bits are restricted to either 0000 or 1111. 
        //That's either number 0 * 16 = 0 or number 15 * 16 = 240. I multiplied by 2^4 because it's shifted
        //4 bytes to the left.
        byte higherBits = (byte)(rnd.Next(0, 2/*upper bound exclusive*/) == 1?240:0);
        //random lower bits (xxxx).
        byte lowerBits = (byte)(Math.Pow(2,0) * rnd.Next(0, 2) + Math.Pow(2,1) * rnd.Next(0, 2) + 
            Math.Pow(2,2) * rnd.Next(0, 2) + Math.Pow(2,3) * rnd.Next(0, 2) + 
            rnd.Next(0, 16));

        byte restrictedByte3 = (byte)(lowerBits + higherBits);

        byte restrictedByte4 = 143; //constant

        //Create an Int32 from the four bytes.
        int randomMutation = BitConverter.ToInt32(
            new byte[] { randomByte[1], restrictedByte2, restrictedByte3, restrictedByte4 }, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks. Sure you can use an int instead of a bool array but what do you do if you have constraints (e.g. possible value between [x ... y])?

Comment: This is a very cool question. I assumed a case where there are constraints and I added a way to tackle this problem in my answer above because I needed to illustrate with code. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at this.